# Webpack String Replace Ionic 3 / Cordova 5 Config.xml

Tags: webpack, ionic3

How to use webpack to replace strings in /config.xml? I can replace strings in .ts files using string-replace-webpack-plugin but can't figure out how to replace strings in config.xml (or if this is even possible with webpack).

Ionic provides an out-of-the-box webpack for standard builds (included below). I've written a custom webpack and use webpack-merge (so that I don't have change the original webpack).

I was able to hack the out-of-the-box webpack to add an additional entry to config.xml but even though the string replace logged successfully to console the final build didn't include the string replacement.

This plugin seems perfect [replace-in-file-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file-webpack-plugin) except it does a replace "after" compilation is done.

Would a webpack pre-loader be more appropriate here or some other approach?

**global.variables.ts Successfully Updated:**

```
export const test: string = '!ReplaceMe!';
```

**My Custom Webpack:**

```
const path = require('path');
const { dev, prod } = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var stringReplacePlugin = require('string-replace-webpack-plugin');

const customConfig = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // This replacement does NOT work.
            {
                test: /config.xml$/,
                loaders: [
                    'raw-loader',
                    stringReplacePlugin.replace({
                        replacements: [
                            {
                                pattern: /!(\w*?)!/ig,
                                replacement: function (match, p1, offset, string) {
                                    console.log('Success xml!') // This is NOT logged to the console.
                                    return 'Replaced!';
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            },
            // This replacement works.
            {
                test: /global.variables.ts$/,
                loader: stringReplacePlugin.replace({
                    replacements: [
                        {
                            pattern: /!(\w*?)!/ig,
                            replacement: function (match, p1, offset, string) {
                                console.log('Success ts!') // This is successfully logged to the console.
                                return 'Replaced!';
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new stringReplacePlugin()
    ]
}

module.exports = {
    dev: webpackMerge(customConfig, dev),
    prod: webpackMerge(customConfig, prod)
};
```

**Ionic 3 Out-Of-The-Box Webpack:**

```
/*
 * The webpack config exports an object that has a valid webpack configuration
 * For each environment name. By default, there are two Ionic environments:
 * "dev" and "prod". As such, the webpack.config.js exports a dictionary object
 * with "keys" for "dev" and "prod", where the value is a valid webpack configuration
 * For details on configuring webpack, see their documentation here
 * https://webpack.js.org/configuration/
 */

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ionicWebpackFactory = require(process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_FACTORY);

var ModuleConcatPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/ModuleConcatenationPlugin');
var PurifyPlugin = require('@angular-devkit/build-optimizer').PurifyPlugin;

var optimizedProdLoaders = [
  {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: [
      {
        loader: process.env.IONIC_CACHE_LOADER
      },

      {
        loader: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: [
      {
        loader: process.env.IONIC_CACHE_LOADER
      },

      {
        loader: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true
        }
      },

      {
        loader: process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_LOADER
      }
    ]
  }
];

function getProdLoaders() {
  if (process.env.IONIC_OPTIMIZE_JS === 'true') {
    return optimizedProdLoaders;
  }
  return devConfig.module.loaders;
}

var devConfig = {
  entry: process.env.IONIC_APP_ENTRY_POINT,
  output: {
    path: '{{BUILD}}',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: ionicWebpackFactory.getSourceMapperFunction(),
  },
  devtool: process.env.IONIC_SOURCE_MAP_TYPE,

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [path.resolve('node_modules')]
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_LOADER
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    ionicWebpackFactory.getIonicEnvironmentPlugin(),
    ionicWebpackFactory.getCommonChunksPlugin()
  ],

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};

var prodConfig = {
  entry: process.env.IONIC_APP_ENTRY_POINT,
  output: {
    path: '{{BUILD}}',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: ionicWebpackFactory.getSourceMapperFunction(),
  },
  devtool: process.env.IONIC_SOURCE_MAP_TYPE,

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [path.resolve('node_modules')]
  },

  module: {
    loaders: getProdLoaders()
  },

  plugins: [
    ionicWebpackFactory.getIonicEnvironmentPlugin(),
    ionicWebpackFactory.getCommonChunksPlugin(),
    new ModuleConcatPlugin(),
    new PurifyPlugin()
  ],

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};


module.exports = {
  dev: devConfig,
  prod: prodConfig
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the @angular-devkit/build-optimizer which @ionic/app-scripts leverages with version 0.0.35, for app-scripts version 3.1.8 and I updated @angular-devkit/build-optimizer to version 0.6.8. Now I can do a production build with ionic 3.9.2 and firebase 5.3.0